# problem with accessing a freshly defined Vector via []

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++, and I'm using Xcode to create a program which lets you fill a vector
<string> with words, while replacing certain unwanted words with "BLEEP". Here is the code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{

    vector<string> words;
    
    vector <string> disliked;
    disliked[0] = "Brocolli";
    
    string temp;
    
    while (cin >> temp)
    {
        words.push_back(temp);
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < words.size() ; ++i)
        {
            
            int current = i;

            for(int i = 0 ; i < disliked.size() ; ++i)
            {
                if (words[current] == disliked[i])
                {
                    words[current] = "BLEEP";
                }
            }
            
            cout << words[current] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, it shows me the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd24C.jpg)

Comment: You use `words.push_back()` but do not use it for `disliked` why?

Comment: [operator[pos\]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) for vector returns a reference to the element at specified location pos without performing bound check. In your case the vector is emptry, as such you are triggering undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
    disliked[0] = "Brocolli";
```

is bad because it is accessing 1st element of a vector with zero elements.

It should be

```
    disliked.push_back("Brocolli");
```

Comment: I am a troglodyte. Thank you, and I'm sorry for wasting your time.